# SQL Server database project pre- and post-deployment script

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, sql-server-data-tools, database-project

I've added an extra column to a table which I want to initialize using a query in the post deployment script. Unfortunately I can't seem to write a query which can be run every time so I'm looking for a way to check in the pre-deployment script if the column is available and pass an argument or variable to the post-deployment script which will then run the initialization query once.

**Attempt 1:** I tried setting a `sqlcmd` var in the pre-deployment script but the following syntax isn't allowed:

```
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.Table','NewColumn') IS NULL
    :setvar PerformInitQuery 1
```

**Attempt 2:** I've also tried using a normal variable in the pre-deployment script:

```
DECLARE @PerformInitQuery BIT = 0
IF COL_LENGTH('dbo.Table','NewColumn') IS NULL
    SET @PerformInitQuery = 1
```

And accessing it in the post-deployment script:

```
IF @PerformInitQuery = 1
BEGIN
    :r ".\DeploymentScripts\PerformInitQuery.sql"
END
```

This last attempt seemed to work when publishing the project from Visual Studio but not on our build server; which uses `SqlPackage.exe` to publish the generated `.dacpac` file to the database.

> Error SQL72014: .Net SqlClient Data Provider:
>
> Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Line 12
>   Must declare the scalar variable "@PerformInitQuery"

Comment: A normal variable won't work because it only exists within a single batch. The deployment will use multiple batches. Just check the create script and you'll see multiple `GO` statements. Why not add the same check that you do in your pre-deployment to your post-deployment?

Comment: Because the build will create the column before the post-deployment script runs so I have no way to determine if it was created this run or a run before

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using a temp table to hold values you wish to pass from pre to post scripts;

```
/*
     Pre-Deployment Script Template                         
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     This file contains SQL statements that will be executed before the build script.   
     Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the pre-deployment script.          
     Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
     Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the pre-deployment script.        
     Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
                   SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    */

    select 'hello world' as [Col] into #temptable
```

picked up in post deployment script;

```
/*
Post-Deployment Script Template                         
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 This file contains SQL statements that will be appended to the build script.       
 Use SQLCMD syntax to include a file in the post-deployment script.         
 Example:      :r .\myfile.sql                              
 Use SQLCMD syntax to reference a variable in the post-deployment script.       
 Example:      :setvar TableName MyTable                            
               SELECT * FROM [$(TableName)]                 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*/

declare @var nvarchar(200)
select @var = [Col] from #temptable

print @var
```

> hello world
>
> Update complete.

Comment: Thanks, this did the job!